# how to call some parameters from web service in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web service and I want to send a parameter(txtCodePers.Text) to it and get two values from web service. Here is my code but it works slowly and load the image after about 4 seconds.Could anyone recommends me another code in which there is not foreach!

```
 protected void btnFind_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         localhost.Personel lp1 = new localhost.Personel();
         DataSet ds1 = lp1.daryafte_view_Personel_Information_with_parameter_cu_personal_number(txtCodePers.Text.Trim());
         this.GridView1.DataSource = ds1;
         foreach (System.Data.DataTable tabale in ds1.Tables)
         {
             foreach (DataRow dr in tabale.Rows)
             {
                 txtName.Text = dr["tp_firstabbr_name"].ToString().Trim() + "  " + dr["tp_familyoffice_name"].ToString().Trim();
                 txtMoavenat.Text = dr["tp_moavenat"].ToString().Trim();
                 Image1.ImageUrl = "~/image/" + txtCodePers.Text + ".jpg";
             }
         }
     }
```

Comment: _...but it works slowly..._ What does "slowly" mean?

Comment: Just select the last row of the last table and you go from O(n) to O(1). As is, you iterate every row in every table just to end up with exactly those values.

Comment: BTW: You are blocking your Event Thread. Even if it is a local call, you'd probably want this to be async I/O.

Comment: @Fildor could you please write the code for me?

Comment: @B001ᛦ I mean the image loads so slowly

Comment: Images kann be tiny up to _very_ large. You really need to disclose a little bit more context and background information if you expect any useful suggestions. A good thing for new users is always to take the [tour] and read [ask] (_at least_).

Comment: Did you solve it farzaneh khanoom?

Comment: @B001ᛦ Unfortunatelly no!